# How to append data to JQuery control variable dynamically in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to display report in Jquery calender control in ASP.net for that I need to retrieve data from Database .I wrote a service like this

```
    [WebMethod]
public static string GetData()
{
    Horticulture h = new Horticulture();
    return h.GetProjectedYield().GetXml();
}
```

Here I'm converting dataset to xml and then I'm calling that function in javascript as follows

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 var response;
     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         contentType: 'application/json',
         url: 'ProjectedYieldCalender.aspx/GetData',
         data: '{}',
         success:
                function (res) {
                    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(res.d);                      
                    var xml = $(xmlDoc);
                    var customers = xml.find("Table1");
                }

     });
```

And then I need to bind the retrived data to JQuery Calender control as follows

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
         header: {
             left: 'prev,next today',
             center: 'title',
             right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
         },
         //defaultDate: '2014-08-12',
         editable: true,
         eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
         events: [
               for(var i=0; i<customers.length; i++)
            {
            "{"

                "title:" +customers[i].Column1+","
                "start:"+customers[i].Column3
                "}"


            if(i!=customers.length-1)
            {
                ","
            }   

            }

    ]
     });

 });
```

but I'm not getting the proper output (unable to find) but I need to generate this as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: '2014-11-12',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2014-11-01'
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: '2014-11-07',
                end: '2014-11-10'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2014-11-09T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2014-11-16T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Conference',
                start: '2014-11-11',
                end: '2014-11-13'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2014-11-12T10:30:00',
                end: '2014-11-12T12:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: '2014-11-12T12:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2014-11-12T14:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Happy Hour',
                start: '2014-11-12T17:30:00'
            }
        ]
    });

});
```

Can any one please let e know how to do this ? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple - do not return XML in web service, return List of event objects.

```
public class CEvent
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string title {get;set;}
    public DateTime start {get;set;}
}

[WebMethod]
public List<CEvent> GetData()
{
    return new List<CEvent>{...};
}

$(document).ready(function () {
 var response;
     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         contentType: 'application/json',
         url: 'ProjectedYieldCalender.aspx/GetData',
         data: '{}',
         success:
                function (data) {
                    var eventList = data;
                    // OR var eventList = data.d
                    initCalendar(eventList);
                }

     });

function initCalendar(eventList){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: '2014-11-12',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: eventList
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. can you give me more clarity on `events: eventList` how to generate that above string in events

Comment: Nothing is displaying on web browser even the Calender if I do like you mention above.Please let me know where  am I wrong?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () ` is not firing even if I place static content